# How to work around Response / Server which does not exist in the context?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have this C# ASP.NET 4 website.

I would like to have a general method in a class which will include a Response.Redirect or Server.Transfer in it to a specific page.

Both names, Response and Server, does not exist in the context.

How to work this around?

---

as for the comment by @Maess, please consider something like this (edited):

**ASPX:**

```
<asp:Button onclick="MyClass.btnRedirect_Click" ID="btnMyButton" Text="MyButtonText" runat="server" />
```

**Code behind:**

```
public static void btnRedirect_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Response.Redirect("~/SomePage.aspx");
}
```

Comment: Please post the code in question.

Answer (score 2):

You'll find these as properties within `HttpContext.Current`

Comment: And can then null check for when HttpContext.Current doesn't exist because your class is being consumed somewhere you didn't expect...

Answer (score 0):

You can use `System.Web.HttpContext.Current`, but be careful. If there is no HTTP context at the time these methods are called you will get an exception.

It is probably safer to have these classes either require an HttpContext in the constructor or have the methods that require an HttpContext to have them in the method signature.

For instance, maybe you have a class which needs to redirect as you mentioned. Your method signature might look like this: `public void CustomRedirect(HttpContext context)` then within the body of your signature you would do something like this: `context.Response.Redirect("...")`. Basically, you make the class or method dependent upon having an HttpContext.

Answer (score 0):

Don't directly reference anything involving the HTTP/IIS stack if you're ever going to be called outside of it.

Your best bet is probably to have your class or method accept either a delegate or an object that implements an interface provided by the calling code. When you're ready to redirect, call that delegate/interface method with the URI (or enough information to construct it) and then the calling code can respond with a server.transfer, a response.redirect or a passing unit test.

```
public static void ButtonRedirect()
{
    MyClass foo = new MyClass(delegate(string s) { Server.Transfer(s); });
    foo.DoThings();
}

public class MyClass
{
    private Action<string> redirector;

    public MyClass(Action<string> redirectAction)
    {
        redirector = redirectAction;
    }

    public void DoThings()
    {
        //Doing stuff
        //Aha! this should redirect
        redirector("/go/to/here");
    }
}
```

Comment: can you show an example how to implement that on my example above?

Comment: I must admit I do not understand how to implement your code in a webpage and a class. There is no Main in a webpage, so there is no way to delegate (right?). The thing is to avoid extra code on each page. If I have to declare the class on each page, what is there to gain?

Comment: You don't need a main for a delegate. If it makes the example clearer, pretend it's your ButtonRedirect event. I'll update accordingly. The MyClass would be the class you're talking about in your original question, where you talk about wanting to have a class that needs to redirect without having access to the Response or Server objects. You would declare it wherever you were planning on putting that class you mentioned.

Comment: The example looks almost the same I use today:
The directive is without the `MyClass.` 
`<asp:Button onclick="btnRedirect_Click" ID="btnMyButton" Text="MyButtonText" runat="server" />` 
and the code behind method is in the code behind of the page and of different type: 
`protected void btnRedirect_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{Response.Redirect("~/SomePage.aspx");}` 
The answer here for the original question works (using `HttpContext.Current`) but I can't call a method from a class: `Compiler Error Message: CS1061: 'ASP.default_aspx' does not contain a definition for 'MyClass' ...`

Comment: Well, you need to write the class. That's a sample of a technique, not code you should paste into your application. I'm just showing you how a class could handle redirects while being decoupled from a dependency on Request and Server. I guess I'm still not clear on what it is that you're trying to do.